# how can I assign an existing key pair to a debian repository/artifactory

Tags: artifactory

I have a debian repository setup in JFrog, I also have a private/public key pair setup
under Administration -> Services -> Artifactory -> RSA Key Pairs
I can see the key pair with certain resources assigned to it, including some debian repos
question is how can I add another resource (debian repo) to this list, and get it to use the key pair

[image: RSA key pair list]

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the key in the desired repo(s).
In Project Settings > Repositories, choose a repo. Under Advanced > GPG Key Pair, specify Primay Key Name.
Of course, The GPG key must be known by clients, still valid and clients must be constrained to check GPG keys (gpgcheck=1 in /etc/yum.conf).